# 'Having' not working in stored procedure with input parameter in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I wrote following procedure in sql server, and passed the parameter as 'D'. It is not giving any result(zero row).

```
create  PROCEDURE USP1
(   
       @p_flag_status   VARCHAR(3)

 )

AS   
BEGIN    
PRINT N'This message was printed on '
+ (@p_flag_status)
+ N'.';


(SELECT Edit_mnemonic,
  action,
  COUNT(Edit_mnemonic) COUNT
FROM claim_line_edit

  GROUP BY Edit_mnemonic,
  action 
  having ltrim(rtrim(action))= @p_flag_status    
  )   


END;
```

But message printed is:

```
This message was printed on 'D'.
```

..............

But if i hardcode the input parameter value in procedure and rewrite the procedure as:

```
 create  PROCEDURE USP1
(   
       @p_flag_status   VARCHAR(3)

 )

 AS   
 BEGIN  

PRINT N'This message was printed on '
+ (@p_flag_status)
+ N'.';


 (SELECT Edit_mnemonic,
  action,
  COUNT(Edit_mnemonic) COUNT
  FROM claim_line_edit

  GROUP BY Edit_mnemonic,
  action 
  having ltrim(rtrim(action))= 'D'


  )   
 END;
```

It is returning result with one row having 3 column values.

Why it is happening so? What i did wrong?

Comment: That's the output of your print statement. have you checked the query output tab?

Comment: yes, no result :(...    I showed printed message so that others can see that input parameter is available as 'D' inside procedure, but still not working.

Comment: What is the schema for the table, specifically `action`?

Comment: [varchar](258) is data type of action. does it answer your requirement?

Comment: Looks like the fault is in the *calling* code, rather than the stored proc itself. But you've not shown us that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your issue comes from the fact that you are passing *'D'* to the stored procedure.
Could you try something like this :
`exec USP1 'D'` instead of `exec USP 1 '''D'''`

The printed message should look like :

> This message was printed on D.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that it's not working though I don't see any reason for that. It could be one of the problem where parameter don't work due to stale procedure cached plan.

Try, re-compiling your procedure either by dropping/re-creating the procedure (OR) by `ALTER PROCEDURE...` statement and then run it. Hopefully that will solve the issue.

Also, `COUNT` is a keyword and so escape it properly

```
COUNT(Edit_mnemonic) [COUNT]
```

Comment: i did recomilation and changing, recreating the procedure more that 10 times. No improvement.

Comment: What if you move that condition to `where ltrim(rtrim(action))= 'D'`. make sure you don't have any special control character on parameer `@p_flag_status`

Comment: it leads to incorrect syntax....... Also  i would like to stress that i want my first procedure to be running( without hard coded value)

Comment: for a moment make this change `@p_flag_status   CHAR(1)` and call proc `exec USP1 'D'` ... kind a hunch

Comment: i have already tried that, and then printed message contains only " ' " instead of " 'D'  ". so it wont work anyway.